# Jquery Autocomplete key press down display label name rather than value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Is there a way you can force jQueryUI autocomplete to display data label rather than data value:

For example

> [{"label":"name","value":"1"},{"label":"name3","value":"6"},{"label":"name1","value":"8"},{"label":"name2","value":"10"}]

```
$( ".auto-search" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    dataType: 'json',
    source: tempJson,
    focus: function(event, ui){
        $('input[name="user-name"]').val(ui.item.label);
    },
    select: function (event,ui){
        $('input[name="user-name"]').val(ui.item.label);
        $('input[name="user-id"]').val(ui.item.value);
        return false;
    }
})
```

The above code, when you press the down button, displays the value rather than the label. Can it be changed to show the label?

Comment: try return your json [{label:"name",value:"1"}] , ie:without double quotation

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure to `return false` or prevent the default action of the event from your `focus` event handler:

```
focus: function(event, ui){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('input[name="user-name"]').val(ui.item.label);
},
```

Comment: Wow andrew that's looks like correct answer, i will give it a go tongiht Thanks + 1 first.

Answer (score 0):

The callback function is not working on me. so i used a bind event `autocompletefocus` and worked just fine.

```
$('input[name="user-name"]').on("autocompletefocus", function (event, ui) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $(this).val(ui.item.label);
});
```